# Is there a way to overlap two images on SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm working on a report (SSRS 2008) that should display a image as background and another one that overlaps the first one. The thing is that when I preview the report, the image is displaced below the background. I've checked this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159193.aspx, it clearly says that "ZIndex Determines which item is position first in the case of overlapping items.". But so far I haven't found how to achieve that (overlapping two Images items), the option (ZIndex) is not enabled at Properties tab for an Image item.

Also I asked to MS the team and they say that it's no possible. But, the weird thing is that if one uses a Rectangle as background image, it's possible to overlaps an image over the Rectangle.

Have you ever face this issue? Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: @Jonnus: Is there a way to overlap two images on SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, as Microsoft have informed you - it is not possible to overlap two image items.  You cannot overlap *ANY* items in Reporting Services in general, only insert items into areas of other items.

See the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255248(v=sql.105).aspx) reference on this subject, specifically

> Overlapping report items are not supported in HTML, MHTML, Word, Excel, in Preview, or the Report Viewer. If overlapping items exist, they are moved.

Answer (score 0):

This is technically not true. Say you wanted to overlap two of the same images over one another. They are the same exact dimensions, the only difference is that one is Black and White, the other is full color. If there is a binary switch somewhere in the visibility expression having one visible and one not visible at all times (opposites), than you can overlay two images so long as you are **only using** one. You would have to use the visibility expression property complete this functionality, and then it would probably be a good idea to place both images in a rectangle to ensure the spacing you desired remains constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can overlap two images by using two tables.  Create One table (1 row by 1 column) and place the background image in the cell.  Duplicate the table but make the image your top image.  This will only work if your top image has a clear background (PNG).  Make sure your cells in both tables are the same size.  Move the first table in to the correct position.  Click on the second table, and using your arrow keys, move it on top of the first table, properly aligning it.  DO NOT drag and drop because this will place the second table within the first one.  When you run the report, click on the "Print Layout" view to properly check the alignment.